# How to disable magento to go on maintenance mode while installing the extension

Tags: magento-1, magento-connect

I am trying to disable the **Put store on the maintenance mode while installing/upgrading/backup creation** under Magento connect in Magento admin.But I am unable to do that?

Is it possible to disable this feature, if yes how?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the "maintenance mode" does is creating empty semaphore file `maintenance.flag` to store root folder. You can create the file manually if you want to, however you can't get into backend interface after that. You can also delete it manually.

Maintenance flag behavior itself is simple and it can be found from `index.php` file:

```
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Can I disable this setting in admin?, It put store on maintenance mode while installing the extension.See the screen shot If I uncheck the checkbox, this setting is not saved.

Comment: You cannot even open backend as `index.php` quits immediately before loading the "god" class (`require_once $mageFilename;`). You must delete the file manually. Personally, I consider this behavior a "misfeature" (frontend and backend maintenance should be separate).

As of turning it off completely; there's no elegant way to do that. As you can see, the behavior is hard coded to `index.php` and nothing short of changing it helps you. It's core file however which means that whenever you upgrade the change gets wiped off.

Answer (score 1):

## **PERMANENT SOLUTION**

Open the `index.php` file from your Root folder:

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile))
{
    // include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    $path="maintenance.flag";
    unlink($path);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Do not modify core files , it is not a good practice

Answer (score 1):

Choose .htaccess file from the root directory And add the following code lines on the top: 
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

Now create your custom HTML i.e.index.html file and you are done.

The other way you can add the following code :
create > maintenance.flag And upload to the root folder of the website.

Answer (score 1):

For **Magento 2.0**, the process has [changed slightly](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html).
Now, the filename is `.maintenance.flag` and it goes into the `var` directory under your Magento root.

For example, if you're running a LAMP stack with Magento 2.0 installed to /var/www/public_html/ then you could use `touch /var/www/public_html/.maintenance.flag` to enable maintenance mode and `rm /var/www/public_html/.maintenance.flag` to disable it.

The [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html) also provides instructions on how to exempt specific IP addresses from maintenance mode to allow that traffic continued to access the site for testing.